# Looking for an HTML parser to do search/replaces on text nodes

Tags: html, html-parsing, replace, textnode

I need to do a lot of various search and replaces within A LOT of **static html files**.  One issue I'm coming up with is I'm getting matches in urls when really **all I want to search/replace are text nodes**.

So that makes regular expressions more difficult and most likely more error prone since you're parsing html with them now.

What's the **easiest** way to do search/replaces on only text nodes?  I'm talking like you can be up and running within a couple minutes with no Master's required in Python-Java-Ruby-Headless-Phantom-PHP-Node-FluxCapacitor.

Please give advice as though you're speaking to a moron.

I'm on **Windows 7**.

What I'm looking for is something like the search/replace functionality in Notepad++.  You give it a directory to start searching, it searches recursively, hitting every type of file you specify (like .html or .shtml) you tell it what to search for and what to replace it with.  It runs and 10 or 15 seconds later you might have edited hundreds of files in one fell swoop.  You know, dead simple stuff.

So that's what I want to do, but just searching/replacing within text nodes.

Answer (score 0):

SublimeText 2 has some very powerful text searching features that should empower you to be able to do as you are explaining, so whilst i think i can point you in the right direction - I myself am still learning how to use it - but it does have the "find in files" option which means you can grab the selected word in many different files and replace it - but I havn't found a way to exclude the irrelevant ones that may not need changing. Hopefully someone else will come along and enlighten you.

You may want to add the tag "Sublime text 2" to your original post to broaden the audience

Comment: Doesn't really help if you can't exclude irrelevant matches.  Notepad++ has the same problem which is why I started looking into regex search/replaces.  Also, I don't want to buy software for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python and HTQL at http://htql.net.  Some examples:

```
page="<html> <body> <table> <tr><td id='cell1'> test1 </td></tr> <tr> <td id='cell2'> test2 </td> </tr> </table> </body> </html>"

import htql
print(htql.query(page, "<td (id='cell1')>:tx &replace('XXXX') "))
#[("<html> <body> <table> <tr><td id='cell1'>XXXX</td></tr> <tr> <td id='cell2'> test2 </td> </tr> </table> </body> </html>",)]

print(htql.query(page, "<td (id='cell1')>:id &replace('ZZZZ') "))
#[("<html> <body> <table> <tr><td id='ZZZZ'> test1 </td></tr> <tr> <td id='cell2'> test2 </td> </tr> </table> </body> </html>",)]

print(htql.query(page, "<td (id like 'cell%')>:tx &replace('YYYY') "))
#[("<html> <body> <table> <tr><td id='cell1'>YYYY</td></tr> <tr> <td id='cell2'>YYYY</td> </tr> </table> </body> </html>",)]
```